# Passing Commands to Button in ContentView

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a `ContentView` with a button inside a grid. I made bindable property for the text value on the button, and the command. The text value is being set properly, but not the button? I don't understand what's going on here. Anyone have any insights?

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Aboo.Components.BusyButton"
             BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}}">
  <ContentView.Content>
      <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="Button" Text="{Binding Text}" Command="{Binding Command}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
        <ActivityIndicator Grid.Column="1" IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" Color="White"/>
      </Grid>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

And code-behind:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class BusyButton : ContentView
{
    public BusyButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("Text", typeof(string), typeof(BusyButton), default(string));

    public string Text
    {
        get => (string) GetValue(TextProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(BusyButton), default(ICommand));

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get => (ICommand) GetValue(CommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsBusyProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("IsBusy", typeof(bool), typeof(BusyButton), default(bool), propertyChanged: IsBusyChanged);

    private static void IsBusyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
    {
        var busyButton = bindable as BusyButton;
        if (busyButton == null)
            return;
        busyButton.Button.IsEnabled = !(bool) newvalue;
    }

    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get => (bool) GetValue(IsBusyProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsBusyProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Using the button like this:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please delete the `BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}}"` this line.

Add the `Content.BindingContext = this;` in your `BusyButton` constructor. Based on my test `BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}}"` not worked in the nasted binding.

Please add a name  `x:Name="MyButton"` for `Button` in `ContentView`, then change the button name  in `IsBusyChanged` method.

Here is my test GIF.

[image]

Here is my code.`BusyButton.xaml`

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App2.BusyButton"

             x:Name="MyContentview"
             >
    <ContentView.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="MyButton" Text="{Binding Text}" Command="{Binding Command}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
            <ActivityIndicator Grid.Column="1" IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy,Mode=TwoWay}" Color="White"/>
        </Grid>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

`BusyButton.xaml.cs`

```
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class BusyButton : ContentView
    {
        public BusyButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Content.BindingContext = this;
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
       BindableProperty.Create("Text", typeof(string), typeof(BusyButton), default(string));

        public string Text
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
            set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty =
         BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Command) , typeof(ICommand), typeof(BusyButton), default(ICommand));

        public ICommand Command
        {
            get => (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty);
            set => SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
        }


        public static readonly BindableProperty IsBusyProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("IsBusy", typeof(bool), typeof(BusyButton), default(bool), propertyChanged: IsBusyChanged);

        private static void IsBusyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
        {
            var busyButton = bindable as BusyButton;
            if (busyButton == null)
                return;
            busyButton.MyButton.IsEnabled = !(bool)newvalue;
        }

        public bool IsBusy
        {
            get => (bool)GetValue(IsBusyProperty);
            set => SetValue(IsBusyProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

I test it in the `MainPage.xaml`.

```
   <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <local:BusyButton x:Name="busyButton" Text="{Binding Name}" Command="{Binding ChangeCommand}" IsBusy="{Binding Changed, Mode=TwoWay}"></local:BusyButton>


    </StackLayout>
```

Here is background code.`MainPage.xaml.cs`

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Content.BindingContext = new MyModelView();



        }
    }
```

Here is my test `MyModelView`.

```
    public class MyModelView: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ICommand ChangeCommand { protected set; get; }


        public string Name { get; set; }
        bool _changed = false;


        public bool Changed
        {
            get
            {
                return _changed;
            }

            set
            {
                if (_changed != value)
                {
                    _changed = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Changed");

                }
            }

        }
        public MyModelView() {

            Name = "test";


           ChangeCommand = new Command(() =>
            {

                Changed = true;
                Console.WriteLine("================test Command execute=================");
            });
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Here is my mode.

https://github.com/851265601/XFormsNestedBindingContentView

Comment: Hi, I just tested and it was indeed helpful!